# Spring security не дает пройти авторизацию

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, spring-mvc, spring-security

Есть проект web приложения с использованием Spring security с использованием бд со следующей структурой:[image: структура проекта]

[image: структура приложения]

Дело в том, что мой spring security, по какой-то причине, не авторизует меня даже если я ввожу пароль и логин те, что есть в базе данных. После ввода он опять перебрасывает меня на страницу авторизации. Возможно я допустил ошибку в написании CustomUserDetails и LoginService,который имплементит UserDetailsService.
web.xml у меня содержит только :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

так как все конфиги у меня заданы в Java классах.
WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "web.controller")
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

SpringConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
         return new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource=new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vebinar?useSll=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("Magdenberg");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDao getUserDao(){
        return new UserDaoIml(getJdbcTemplate());
    }
    @Bean
    public UserService getUserService(){
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    public LoginService getLoginService(){
        return new LoginService();
    }
    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

SecurutyConfig:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
        return new MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery(
                "select user.nickname,user.password from alexeydb.user where nickname=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select roles.nickname,  roles.authority from alexeydb.roles where nickname=?")
                .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        auth.userDetailsService(loginService);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl( "/login" ).loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                //.successHandler(new MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .usernameParameter("nickname").passwordParameter("password")
                .failureForwardUrl("/login?error").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/","/reg");
    }
}
```

MvcWebApplicationInitializer :

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class, SpringConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

SpringWebSecurityApplicationInitializer :

```
public class SpringWebSecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer  {
    public SpringWebSecurityApplicationInitializer() {

    }
}
```

CustomUserDetails :

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    private UserDao loginDao;

    public CustomUserDetails(final User user, UserDao _loginDao) {
        super(user);
        loginDao=_loginDao;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<String> roles = loginDao.getUserRoles(getUsername());

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        if(roles!=null){
            for(String role : roles){
                GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
                grantedAuthorityList.add(authority);
            }
        }
        return grantedAuthorityList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return getNickname();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

LoginService:

```
@Service
public class LoginService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao loginDao;

    public void setLoginDao(UserDao loginDao) {
        this.loginDao = loginDao;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        web.entity.User userInfo = loginDao.findByUsername(username);

        if(userInfo==null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user name not found");
        }

        List<String> roles = loginDao.getUserRoles(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        if(roles!=null){
            for(String role : roles){
                GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
                grantedAuthorityList.add(authority);
            }
        }
        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails=new CustomUserDetails(userInfo,loginDao);

        return customUserDetails;
    }
}
```

Прилагаю весь проект по ссылке:
https://bitbucket.org/denisbaic10000/java_web/downloads/

Comment: Смотри SecurityConfig #void configure(HttpSecurity http). Только здесь может быть редирект

Comment: Возможно ты неправильно ввёл пути авторизации.